# curl_setopt returning false with CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE

Tags: php, curl

PHP version 5.4.19 under FreeBSD

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //returns true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //returns true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6'); //returns true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100); //returns true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //returns true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); //returns true
var_dump(curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) ); //true
var_dump( curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1) ); //returns false ???? 
var_dump( curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookie') ); //returns false ????
var_dump( curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookie') ); //returns false ????
var_dump( curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true) ); //true
```

I've also noticed, that even without CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE - Curl is not passing any cookie between requests in single handler.
Here is some headers log to understand what I'm talking about:

```
GET /login.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6
Host: domain.com
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 08:25:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=bev3mvr9s27jgq5vvm43s56pb2; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: go.php?PHPSESSID=bev3mvr9s27jgq5vvm43s56pb2

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 08:25:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=m8uddnk1q55s634fu7frnt2lo3; path=/ 
    #session cookie has changed; Curl didn't use PHPSESSID cookie from login.php
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: login.php
```

**UPDATE:** I've tried the same code on another host - everything is ok. Hm...

Comment: is the file exist at **/tmp/cookie**??

Comment: PHP get permissions to read and write?

Comment: @AllenChak, nope, but /tmp is writeable. But really it doesn't matter. I can remove CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, but Curl is still not passing any cookies even between redirects :(

Comment: Could you create a file at there & change it permission to 666??? In my past project, my code same with you, different of file placed at same directory with granted permission instand of /tmp/.

Comment: @AllenChak, thank you. I've tried another file, created via PHP with 666 permission (in application folder, not in /tmp/). Still no effect.

Comment: I've tried the same code on another host - everything is ok. Hm...

Comment: they are using same PHP and cURL version ?

Comment: @AllenChak, curl was compiled with `--disable-cookies`. I don't know why, really. I've compiled with `--enable-cookies` now everything is fine! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but Curl was compiled without cookies support. Just reinstalled it with `--enable-cookies` - that's it.